# Pytorch: Fast create score tensor method

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to Pytorch and am looking for a quick get score function. That, given a bunch of samples and a distribution, outputs a tensor consisting of the corresponding score for each individual sample. For instance, consider the following code:

```
norm = torch.distributions.multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal(torch.zeros(2),torch.eye(2))
samples = norm.sample((1000,))
samples.requires_grad_(True)
```

Using `samples` I would like to create a `score` tensor of size `[1000,2]` where the ith component `score[i]` is the gradient of `log p(samples[i])`, where `p` is the density of the given distribution. The method I have come up with is the following:

```
def get_score(samples,distribution):
    log_probs = distribution.log_prob(samples)
    for i in range(log_probs.size()[0]):
        log_probs[i].backward(retain_graph = True)
```

The resulting `score` tensor is then `samples.grad`. The issue is that my method is quite slow for larger samples (e.g. for a sample of size `[50000,2]` it takes about 25-30 seconds on my CPU). Is this as fast as it can get?

The only alternative I can think of is to hard-code the score function for each distribution I will use, this doesn't seem like a good solution!

---

From experimentation, for 50000 samples, the following is about 50% quicker:

```
for i in range(50000):
    sample = norm.sample((1,))
    sample.requires_grad_(True)
    log_prob = norm.log_prob(a)
    log_prob.backward()
```

This indicates that there should be a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that log_probs is stored as a pytorch tensor.
You can take advantage of the linearity of differentiation to calculate the derivative for all samples at once: `log_probs.sum().backward(retain_graph = True)`

At least with GPU acceleration this will be a lot faster.

If log_probs is not a tensor but a list of scalars (represented as pytorch tensors of rank 0), you can use `log_probs = torch.stack(log_probs)` first.

Comment: Nice! It was stored as a pytorch tensor and is now essentially instantaneous, thanks